# PasswordChangeForm with Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-forms

I recently implemented my own user model by subclassing abstract user.

`class NewUserModel(AbstractUser):`

After I did this the `PasswordChangeForm` stopped working.  I fixed the issue in the `UserCreationForm` by overriding the `class Meta:` model field.  However, the `ChangePasswordForm` doesn't specify a model and I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work with the new user model.

`views.py`

```
class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'change_password.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PasswordChangeView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just spent most of the day trying to achieve this. Eventually I found out it was pretty simple to implement it with a FBV:

```
@login_required
def UpdatePassword(request):
    form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)

    return render(request, 'user/password.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: Nice!  I'm going to do the same with my CBV.  Will update when I do.

Answer (score 6):

CBV version:

```
    class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
        model = CustomUser
        form_class = PasswordChangeForm
        template_name = 'password_change.html'

        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(PasswordChangeView, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
            if self.request.method == 'POST':
                kwargs['data'] = self.request.POST
            return kwargs

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(self.request, form.user)        
            return super(PasswordChangeView, self).form_valid(form)
```