# Django PasswordChangeForm implementation error

Tags: django, change-password

I am using the Django user system and I am trying to implement their PasswordChangeForm, like so:

```
    class Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
       template_name = 'user/profile.html'
       form_class = PasswordChangeForm
```

As I understand it, this should work, but i keep getting this error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

I dont really understand what that means....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django comes with a built in [`password_change`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) view. It would be easier to use this, rather than use your own. There are [instructions in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).

The current error with your view is that you are not passing the logged in user to the form. You can do this by overriding `get_form_kwargs`.

```
class Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Profile, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Once you get that working, you would also need to override `form_valid()` and save the form so that the new password is set. There might be other code changes required as well, so as I said at the beginning of the answer, you'll find it easier to use the built in view.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are missing to pass the user to the form ?

```
PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457279/passwordchangeform-with-custom-user-model) is quite similar and might help you